# I combined two strings in c++ but get a wrong out put

Tags: c++

```
 while(in) {
memset(str, 0,1024);
in.getline(str, 1024);  // delim defaults to '\n'
string output = modifyString(str);
if (output != ""){
  cout << output << endl;
  string output1 = "INSERT INTO DATA_SRC "\
  "VALUES (" + output + ");";
  cout << output1 << endl;
  const char * command = output1.c_str();
  cout << output << endl;
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, command, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    return 1;
  }
}
```

for here, I + two string together. 
And the out put intially is:
'D3318','D.A. Kline','Quantitative determination of sugars in fruits by GLC separation of TMS derivatives',1970,'Journal of AOAC International',53,6,1198,1202

which is good. But after I combine it to others.

Expected: 
INSERT INTO DATA_SRC VALUES ('D3318','D.A. Kline','Quantitative determination of sugars in fruits by GLC separation of TMS derivatives',1970,'Journal of AOAC International',53,6,1198,1202);

Reality:
INSERT INTO DATA_SRC VALUES ('D3318','D.A. Kline','Quantitative determination of sugars in fruits by GLC separation of TMS derivatives',1970,'Journal of AOAC In);rnational',53,6,1198,1202

I do not now why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I do not know why either, probably because the problem is in `modifyString`, which you don't show?

Comment: did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I agree. Additionally, I think you should change the fixed size array for a more dynamic option: `std::getline(in, str)` and change `str` from `char*` to `std::string`.

Comment: If the issue is with concatenation, why are you showing totally irrelevant calls to `sqllite`?  That space where you're posting these calls could have been used posting the `modifyString` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `modifyString` function (which you didn't show) is copying a null byte to the end of the string. The string output functions will stop on a null byte, in order to be compatible with C-strings.